# How to implement Data change notification from SUP 2.1 to iphone device

Tags: iphone, sup

I have successfully implemented DCN from Sap backend to SUP 2.1 i.e I am able to update CDB of SUP 2.1 but the problem is I have to notify the same to iphone device(iOS 5).

I tried implementing cache policy on schedule in cache group but no success.

Can anyone help me on this

Answer (score 1):

Please visit this blog.

http://scn.sap.com/community/developer-center/mobility-platform/blog/2012/06/11/calling-the-sup-data-change-notification-from-abap

Comment: Please include more than just a link in your answer. If this link were to ever break your post would become useless to future users.